# Polymer.fire is not a function

Tags: polymer

My web-component (Polymer 1.0) changes the light-DOM given with <content> and tries to convert a click into a custom event.

```
<link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="x-custom">
    <template>
        <content></content>
        <!-- used this way <x-custom><div></div></x-custom> -->
    </template>

    <script>
    (function() {

        function init() {
            var myRoot = Polymer.dom(this);
            var firstDiv = myRoot.querySelectorAll("div")[0];
            var itemDiv = document.createElement("div");
            itemDiv.textContent = "Yadda";
            firstDiv.appendChild(itemDiv);

            itemDiv.addEventListener("click", follow);

        }

        function follow()
        {
            console.log("follow");
            Polymer.fire("custom-event");
        }

        Polymer({
            is: 'x-custom',
            ready: init
        });

    })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

It tells me Polymer has no function fire. What's the correct way to call this method? Probably some anti-patterns here too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `fire` method inside of the Polymer object. The fire method is inside Polymer.Base, but you can't use it directly unless you declare a prototype, hence you need `this`. You can view all Polymer properties and methods by opening Dev Tools and typing `Polymer` followed by a dot.

In summary you should use `this.fire`.

```
<dom-module id="x-custom">
    <template>
        <content></content>
        <!-- used this way <x-custom><div></div></x-custom> -->
    </template>

    <script>
    (function() {

        function init() {
            var myRoot = Polymer.dom(this);
            var firstDiv = myRoot.querySelectorAll("div")[0];
            var itemDiv = document.createElement("div");
            itemDiv.textContent = "Yadda";
            firstDiv.appendChild(itemDiv);

            itemDiv.addEventListener("click", follow.bind(this));  // notice the .bind here

        }

        function follow()
        {
            console.log("follow");
            this.fire("custom-event");
        }

        Polymer({
            is: 'x-custom',
            ready: init
        });

    })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks a lot. I guess I will be not the only one getting into trouble here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your functions inside your main `Polymer()` function. It's throwing the error because the `Polymer()` function is not in scope of your `init()` function. You also need to declare inside your `Polymer()` function all custom properties you are using in your template.

---

#### Like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="x-custom">
  <template>
    <content></content>
    <!-- used this way <x-custom><div></div></x-custom> -->
  </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-custom',
        properties: {
          customProperty1: {
            type: String
          },
          customProperty2: {
            type: String
          }
        },
        ready: function() {
          var myRoot = Polymer.dom(this);
          var firstDiv = myRoot.querySelectorAll("div")[0];
          var itemDiv = document.createElement("div");
          itemDiv.textContent = "Yadda";
          firstDiv.appendChild(itemDiv);
          itemDiv.addEventListener("click", follow);
        },
        follow: function() {
          console.log("follow");
          Polymer.fire("custom-event");
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: This way `follow` is unknown when using `addEventListener`. If I workaround that, `fire` is still undefined, also when using `this.fire()`. Polymer is declared in polymer-micro.html just this with `Polymer = {...};` so its globally hanging on windows. Its methods should be callable from anywhere. `fire` is described in the 1.0 API for Polymer.Base.